# Is there anything notable about this way of summing all the natural numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If I have the sum of natural numbers, and group them in groups of three like this:

$S_1 = 1 + (2 + 3 + 4) + (5 + 6 + 7) + ... $

Then I get

$S_1 = 1  + 9 + 18 + 27 + ... = 1 + 9(1 + 2 + 3 + ...)$

$S_1 = 1 + 9S_1$

$S_1 = -1/8$

Similarly if I make groups of five I get

$S_2 = 1 + 2 + (3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7) + (8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12) +...$

$S_2 = 1 + 2 + 25(1 + 2 + 3 + ....) = 1 + 2 + 25S_2 $

$S_2 = -1/8$

In general, the starting ungrouped terms are the sum of numbers up to $n$ and the grouped numbers equal $(2n+1)^2S_n$, so

$S_n = n(n+1)/2 + (2n+1)^2S_n$

with some rearranging,

$S_n = -1/8$

Is there anything notable about this way of summing the natural numbers? I didn't expect that the sum would be the same regardless of how I made the groups. I know that type of maths is full of pitfalls and easy to make mistakes. But I have generally seen that some interpretations can make the sum of natural numbers go to -1/12. Why does this approach give -1/8? Can I group the terms to make any other fractions?

Comment: Please stop using sums that do not converge

Comment: Is that all there is to say? Don't do it?

Comment: Don't touch series without being properly introduced to them by a math teacher, I beg you, you can also delete the idea that the sum of natural numbers equals $-\frac{1}{12}$, I think your computation show that it does not work

Comment: Yes that is all there is to say

Comment: I'm telling you, @JulesBesson - don't tell mathematicians what they can & can't do!

Comment: @Shaun I can, I said "please" :)

Comment: $$\ddot\smile$$

Comment: @user668074 here is some "reference" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics) but you can find various books that are quite good

Comment: This would show that **if** $S$ converges, it is equal to $-1/8.$ But it doesn't converge. This is the problem with the false statement $1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12.$ The Ramanujan sum of this series is $-1/12,$ but the R-sum does not obey simple associate law expectations. The most obvious example is $$1+(-1)+1+(-1)+\cdots=1/2\,(\mathfrak R),$$ but $$(1+(-1))+(1+(-1))+\cdots =0+0+0+\cdots=0.$$

Comment: Another odder example is that while $1+(-1)+1+(-1)+\cdots$ has Ramanujan sum $1/2,$ $1+0+(-1)+1+0+(-1)+\cdots$ has Ramanujan sum $2/3.$ Inserting $0$ into a sum changes the sum. Ramanujan sums do not work as one would expect.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you. So if I found different ways to group the terms, would I expect to get different values? That's what I was trying to do but I kept getting -1/8

Comment: You may like to read about the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

Comment: @kipf, thank you, I will have a look

Comment: Well, the way you've grouped it, you won't get a different value. But if you group it more directly, $(1+2+3)+(4+5+6)+\cdots=3(2+5+8+\cdots)$ will give you a different Ramanujan sum. You can't derive it as simply, however. But again, grouping can break Ramanujan sums.

Comment: "Please stop using sums that do not converge" I agree. Those Ramanujan sums (if Ramanujan used them at all) are not sums in the usual sense , so it should not be claimed that the SUM has the value. This is simply not true. Whether a regularization (or however it is called) makes sense (or is unique at all) is a different story. But this is not what the post does. It uses directly the diverging sum !